# Overseas proxy makes Google Chrome think I am in Germany or Netherlands

Tags: google-chrome, search, proxy

I am in the UK and my firm has an outsourced webscanning service which routes our traffic through either Germany or The Netherlands.

Whenever I do a search using Chrome's Address Bar I get either the .de or .nl results page.

Is there any way to force Chrome to use the .co.uk ignoring the location it thinks I am in?

Internet access is very locked down so alternate proxy suggestions will probably not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force this I added a specific Google UK search entry and made it default:

`Spanner icon` -> `Settings` -> `Basics` tab -> `Default search` section -> `Manage` button

Click the `Add` button and enter the following:

> Name: google.co.uk
>
> Keyword: google.co.uk
>
> URL:
>   http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%s

Click `OK` then select the new entry and click `Make Default`

All done!

All searches will now go through google.co.uk and not the location aware version which uses the following URL:

> {google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s

Comment: I still get results for Sweden using a Swedish proxy when using google.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe turning location aware browsing will help - [this is how.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16404/how-to-disable-the-new-geolocation-feature-in-google-chrome/)

Answer (score 0):

Since switching to the [Beta Channel](http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/) (currently on 5.0.375.38) the problem seems to have sorted itself, I am always getting .co.uk search results now.

Comment: Actually, not! I'm now back on .de this week - the proxy company must rotate it each weekend

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Chrome, but this works for me in any browser: just append /ncr to the google URL (ncr=no country redirect): www.google.com/ncr, www.google.it/ncr, etc.

The /ncr will disappear when the page has been displayed, but the information is still available in a cookie (if you at least accept session cookies).

Comment: the functionality in Chrome is used without a URI - simply entering search terms in the address bar so there is nowhere to put the `/ncr`. Thanks anyway - a good tip otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding `gl=uk` to the search string in the settings of my browser.

I'm using Edge. I added a new search engine, copied & pasted the normal google one, changed it to .co.uk and added the above to the search string. It gave me this:

`https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:prefetchSource}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}&gl=uk`

This gave me .co.uk search with UK results. Without the `gl=uk` part I got swedish results despite it searching .co.uk, using a swedish proxy server.