# Overseas proxy makes Firefox think I am in Germany or Netherlands

Tags: firefox, proxy, geolocation

Well actually doesn't it thinks I'm in France but there already was a question like this but for Chrome, so I thought I may as well frame it the same way

[Overseas proxy makes Google Chrome think I am in Germany or Netherlands](https://superuser.com/questions/137780/overseas-proxy-makes-google-chrome-think-i-am-in-germany-or-netherlands)

I want the same thing but for Firefox, and well websites in general if there is a solution that is more wide ranging

Answer (score 0):

Firefox settings for this are in **Tools -> Options -> Advance -> Network -> Settings** Once, you in here, hit the radio button that states "Manual Proxy Configuration" The HTTP Proxy should be filled in with information that looks like this: 214.15.115.13. The Port should be something like 443, 8080, 80, 3124, or really anything. Proxies can be set to use many different/ all port.

EDIT: Here is another way of making it think you're from somewhere else without using another proxy. Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Content** -> (In the languages section) **Choose** -> **Select Languages to Add**. Select the language you want and click **Add**. Now move that language to the top by have the language you want selected and click the **Move Up** button. Once your language is at the top click **OK** on both of the windows and you are done.

I hope this helps. If you need anymore help, let me know with a comment.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.  My proxy settings are working fine, but unfortunately for my our company proxy is located in France (due to our French parent company).  My problem is that google searches in the omni-bar default to Google.fr through some sort of geo location ability.  However I'm not French, and so French results are useless to me!

Comment: What I meant for you to do is use another proxy. I didn't know you HAD to use the company proxy. If you find another proxy in the US, and use that instead, it will not give you the french Google.

Comment: I just found out how to do what you want. I will add it to my answer.